# StackHunter remote error logging when not in a Servlet Container

Tags: java, error-handling

I correctly installed StackHunter server, now I need to test it by throwing an error in my Java Desktop application.

According to [documentation](https://stackhunter.com/how/) all I need is to:

> Not in a Servlet Container?
>
> If you're not running in a servlet container, you can log exceptions
>   using the API directly:
>
> ```
> com.stackhunter.client.StackHunter.logException(Throwable)
> ```
>
> Or, by using Log4J or Logback, after initializing the API:
>
> ```
> com.stackhunter.client.StackHunter.init()
> ```

however using

```
StackHunter.logException(new Exception("test error..."));
```

does nothing, that's quite reasonable considering I would need to set the password and remote host programatically first, but where and how?

Apparently there's no documentation whatsoever in the official website for a simple programatical way to setup a desktop application to send an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the support pages at https://stackhunter.com/support/.

It sounds like you've already installed (and maybe even setup) the server: https://stackhunter.com/support/setup/install-stackhunter.

If that's the case, try setting up the client: https://stackhunter.com/support/setup/configure-clients.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The documentation you linked is the one I included in my question, very minimal and no practical example on how to setup a client programatically. :(

Comment: Have you generated the **stackhunter-client.properties** and dropped it in your classpath like it says here https://stackhunter.com/support/setup/configure-clients?

Comment: I did but nothing, that's why I'm looking for a programmatical way to setup the class by hand!

Comment: Sorry for your trouble.  Please contact us via the support form at https://stackhunter.com/support/ to get this resolved.  Thanks.